# "Fuzzy" Chinese Remainder Theorem

Tags: time-complexity

I have some "fuzzy" congruences like these:
\begin{align} \\ x&\equiv a_1 \mod 3 \text{ with } a_1 \in \{0,1\},\\ x&\equiv a_2\mod 5 \text{ with } a_2 \in \{2,3,4\},\\x&\equiv a_3 \mod 7 \text{ with } a_3 \in \{5,6\}\\ \end{align}
These example moduli would provide a unique solution for $x \mod lcm(3,5,7)$, if the $a_i$ were fixed. 
Because the $a_i$ are not fixed, these "fuzzy" congruences lead to $2*3*2=12$ possible solutions for $x \mod lcm(3,5,7)$.

To reduce the number of possible solutions for $x$, there exists an additional condition, which provides an upper bound for $x$. For example:
\begin{align} x \mod lcm(3*5*7) &< 5 \end{align}

We can assume that all moduli $m_i$ are primes, f.e. $lcm(m_1,m_2,...) = \prod_i m_i$. 
Furthermore each $a_i$ has at most $t$ possible values ($t=3$ in the upper example). Additionally, the possible values of $a_i$ are consecutive ($a_2 \in \{1,3,4\}$ is not allowed).
So the generic equations look like:
\begin{align} x&\equiv a_i \mod m_i &\text{ with } a_i \in U_i \text{ and } U_i \subset \{0,1,...,m_i-1\} \wedge |U_i| = t \wedge \\&&\forall i,j: |i-j|=1 \Rightarrow |U_i[i]-U_i[j]| = 1
\\ x \mod \prod_i m_i &< k \end{align}

Is it partical feasible to calculate **one** solution for parameters like $\prod_i m_i \approx 10^{1000}$, all $m_i < 100000$, $k \approx 10^{50}$ and $t \approx 50$?

I tried to use the Chinese Remainder Theorem Method to find a solution for x:

Set $M_i:=lcm(m_1,m_2,...)/m_i$. It holds $gcd(M_i,m_i)=1$.

Hence, we can use the Extended Euclidean algorithm to find 2 Integers $r_i$ und $s_i$, which fulfill $r_i \cdot m_i + s_i \cdot M_i = 1$.

Set $e_i:=s_i \cdot M_i$, then \begin{align} e_i &\equiv 1 \mod m_i \\ e_i &\equiv 0 \mod m_j, j \neq i\end{align}.

The number $x:=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot e_i \mod lcm(m_1,m_2,...)$ is a solution.

Now i tried to solve $(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i \cdot e_i \mod \prod_i m_i) < k$ with $minValue(U_i) <= a_i <= maxValue(U_i)$.

These equations can be formulated as an Integer Programming instance (add an additional variable for the mod Operation). I tried to use mathematica to solve these, but it seems unfeasible even for "small" parameters like $\prod_i m_i \approx 10^{50}$, all $m_i < 1000$, $k \approx 10^{2}$ and $t = 3$.

Is there a more efficent way to solve this?

Comment: Without the "consecutive" requirement, the problem is NP-hard.  I don't know whether that changes when taking into account the "consecutive" requirement.  With this requirement, it seems another way to formulate the problem is: given $b_1,\dots,b_n$ and $m_1,\dots,m_n$ and $c$ and $k$ such that $b_i \le t$ for all $i$, we seek to find $x$ such that $0 \le x < k$ and $x-c \bmod m_i \le b_i$ for each $i$.

Comment: thx for the quick answer! "Without the "consecutive" requirement, the problem is NP-hard.": Could you get me a hint how i can prove this? I tried to develope a reduction-proof with the Integer Programming Problem(ILP), but i don't know how to transform arbitrary ILP-equiations like $\sum_i p_i \cdot v_i < c$ (v_i are the variables and p_i are the const factors) to a “Fuzzy” Chinese Remainder Theorem instance.

Comment: The proof is too long to list in a comment, but if you want to ask a new question about that version, I will answer it with a detailed reduction.

Comment: I also have a question concerning your reformulation of the problem. I'm not sure what these $b_1,...,b_n$ means and how they will change if we alter for example $a_3 \in \{5,6\}$ to $a_3 \in \{2,3\}$. Could you explain it for me by one of the example congruences in the original question?

Answer (score 2):

This problem can be approached with the [Coppersmith method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith_method). For details, see my [answer at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/224033) to a similar question.

Comment: Could you please summarize, or even copy-paste your answer in MO? Link-only answers are not allowed in StackExchange as a general policy.